# Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover-- Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, text, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I am using Eclipse Indigo, i got a premgen space erorr, for that i go to eclipse.ini file and make the memory space their 512M, in place of 256.

From that this, now mu eclipse hangs, and is behaving unexpectedly. The eclipse.ini file is

```
    -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

The log file shows thos error.

```
        !SESSION 2014-11-26 08:56:15.409 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
    java.version=1.7.0_71
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

    This is a continuation of log file D:\CDGL\PSB\.metadata\.bak_0.log
    Created Time: 2014-11-26 10:16:22.442

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface.text 4 0 2014-11-26 10:16:22.445
    !MESSAGE Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.cm.ElementCMAdapter.getLength(ElementCMAdapter.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.basic.CMNamedNodeMapImpl.<init>(CMNamedNodeMapImpl.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.getCMAttributeDeclaration(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.computeTagAttValueHelp(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.computeRegionHelp(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.computeHoverHelp(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.getHoverInfo(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.ui.internal.hover.FaceletHover.getHoverInfo(FaceletHover.java:58)
        at org.jboss.tools.common.text.xml.info.ChainTextHover.getHoverInfo2(ChainTextHover.java:145)
        at org.jboss.tools.common.text.xml.info.ChainTextHover.getHoverInfo2(ChainTextHover.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:166)

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface.text 4 0 2014-11-26 10:19:54.785
    !MESSAGE Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.core.internal.cm.ElementCMAdapter.getLength(ElementCMAdapter.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.basic.CMNamedNodeMapImpl.<init>(CMNamedNodeMapImpl.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.getCMAttributeDeclaration(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.computeTagAttValueHelp(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.computeRegionHelp(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.computeHoverHelp(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.taginfo.XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.getHoverInfo(XMLTagInfoHoverProcessor.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.ui.internal.hover.FaceletHover.getHoverInfo(FaceletHover.java:58)
        at org.jboss.tools.common.text.xml.info.ChainTextHover.getHoverInfo2(ChainTextHover.java:145)
        at org.jboss.tools.common.text.xml.info.ChainTextHover.getHoverInfo2(ChainTextHover.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:166)
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-11-27 09:52:17.423
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-11-27 09:54:43.292
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/compare/Splitter
    at org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.VpeEditorPartFactory.createVisualEditor(VpeEditorPartFactory.java:23)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.jsp.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditor.createPagesForVPE(JSPMultiPageEditor.java:481)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.jsp.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditor.createPages(JSPMultiPageEditor.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.requestActivation(PartPane.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.requestActivation(EditorPane.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setFocus(PresentablePart.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.handleMouseDown(AbstractTabFolder.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder$3.mouseDown(AbstractTabFolder.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
!SESSION 2014-11-27 10:02:55.134 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product openFile
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product openFile

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-11-27 10:02:57.599
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost is not set but should be 10.11.20.1.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-11-27 10:02:57.605
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-11-27 10:02:57.607
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be 10.11.20.1.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-11-27 10:02:57.610
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-11-27 10:02:57.613
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be 10.11.20.1.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-11-27 10:02:57.615
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-11-27 10:03:00.237
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-11-27 10:03:00.237
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+DEL:
Binding(CTRL+DEL,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result.removeInstance,Remove Result,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result.category,SQL Results View,null,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+DEL,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.internal.action.RemoveAction,Remove,
        Remove selected Pictogram Elements,
        Category(org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.Graphiti_Category,Edit,Graphiti Diagram Editor,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
```

Comment: Please show your `.ini` file, as well as any possible commands you use when launching

Comment: @Vince Emigh I have shown the eclipse.ini file. Please check

Comment: Why are you declaring `XXMaxPermSize` twice? Back on topic, I found [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361005) post, which explains how this is a known bug, and contains a patch that should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

I changed my ini file to include this

```
 -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

and now eclipse is working fine. This is due to the memory space error, As i increased the memory, it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others having the same issue with Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
Build id: 20200313-1211.

The tool tips providing quick fixes became unusable as they immediately disappeared when attempting to hover over them.

In the logs I saw this message:

```
    eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155
java.version=14
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface.text 4 0 2020-05-08 21:22:43.938
!MESSAGE Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.SelectionEngine$1Visitor.visit(SelectionEngine.java:1489)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Argument.traverse(Argument.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.traverse(Block.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.traverse(Block.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1551)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedAllocationExpression.traverse(QualifiedAllocationExpression.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.SelectionEngine.selectLocalDeclaration(SelectionEngine.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.SelectionEngine.select(SelectionEngine.java:1078)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.codeSelect(Openable.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.codeSelect(CompilationUnit.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.codeSelect(CompilationUnit.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.AbstractJavaEditorTextHover.getJavaElementsAt(AbstractJavaEditorTextHover.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.internalGetHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo2(JavadocHover.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$1.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:155)
```

The solution in my case was a configuration change Windows=>Preferences=>Type Hover and change as shown
[image]